# Haskell: How to throw an error for too few arguments supplied to a function?

Tags: haskell

A newbie question. I would like to throw an elegant error when too few arguments are supplied to a function. You can see, I would like modify the part that's commented out below. Thanks

```
showListConditional :: (Integral a) => a -> [a] -> [a]

--showListConditional undefined y = error "Please specify number of transformation steps as the first argument, before the list!"

showListConditional z y = map head (filter isLong (map chain y))
        where isLong q = fromIntegral (length q) > z
```

Comment: you can not throw an exception for that, since that is checked at compile time.

Comment: Each function in Haskell takes exactly one argument, thanks to currying. The function above, for instance, takes `a` and returns a function `[a]->[a]`. There is no way to detect whether "too few" arguments have been passed. Even if the language allowed that, that would horribly break partial application. Further, in your example, you seem to want to handle the case where the "first" argument is not passed but the "second" one is, which is even prevented by the application syntax.

Comment: This is good practice in Java but not something you do in Haskell. Supplying less arguments than required is totally fine, thanks to currying you just get a new function that you can supply with the remaining arguments later. You also don't need to check for `null` or equivalent, because Haskell doesn't allow `null` in place of actual values.

Comment: In another sense, type checking already catches this for you. If `foo :: [a] -> b`, and you try to call `foo (showListConditional 3)`, the type checker will complain that `showListConditional 3 :: [a] -> [a]` does not match `[a]` expected by `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters have stated, this is not really done in Haskell (because partial application is useful!) but if I wouldn't want a function to be called with 'insufficient' arguments, I would make the argument a tuple. For simplicity, suppose I want to make a function that adds three numbers

```
addThree :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int
addThree (a, b, c) = a + b + c
```

If I try to call **addThree** with less than 3 arguments, the compiler will give me an error.